# Trying to get a String from the firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a restricted sign-up page and I need to get a code from the database but the string is coming back empty and I dont know why. Can anyone help?

Here is the function to read the code:

```
public void codeClinic() {

    DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("CodeClinic").document("Codes");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                codedb = document.getString(clinic.getText().toString());
                Log.d("Code",codedb);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

AndI just call it on a `TextView` on a onClick function to see what it returns and it comes back empty.

Here is the database

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGklL.png)

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `clinic.getText().toString()`?

Comment: its the name of the field.
as you see in the image it can be clinica, FEUP or outra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work, please use the code below:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
rootRef.collection("CodeClinic").document("Codes").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                String clinica = document.getString("Clinica");
                Long feup = document.getLong("FEUP");
                String outra = document.getString("outra");
                Log.d("TAG", clinica + " / " + feup + " / " + outra);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Your output will be: `1111 / 1234 / 2222`.

Comment: Thank you.
The thing is clinic is an EditText, I want to get the code from the text wrote by the user.

And i want to use the code I got on a if function.

Comment: Then use: `clinic.getText().toString()` but be sure that the users enters only one of the following strings: `Clinica`, `FEUP` or `outra`. Otherwise you'll have an error.

Comment: it gives me an empty string

Comment: If you are using this line of code: `String clinica = document.getString("Clinica");` instead of yours, does it work?

Comment: No, still get an empty string

Comment: Please see my updated answer in which I have added the entire code. I have tested myself and it works. Is it also working to you?

Comment: I alredy did, what just the problem of calling variables defined on anther function. thanks a lot